# Laravel optional select field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

In a generic controller I have the next query in Laravel

```
 $query=DB::Table("Enemies")->select("Name",$orderBy,$select[0])
            ->Offset(($page-1)*Context::$PageSize)
            ->Limit(Context::$PageSize)
            ->OrderBy("$orderBy", 'DESC');
```

I pass this cursor to the view where I renderize it to html.

In certain searchs i dont want to show the $orderBy parameter, like this

```
 $query=DB::Table("Enemies")->select("Name",$select[0])
            ->Offset(($page-1)*Context::$PageSize)
            ->Limit(Context::$PageSize)
            ->OrderBy("$orderBy", 'DESC');
```

I just want to remove it "inline"... I dont want to make 2 queries based in a condition like this one

```
if($orderBy=="xxx")
    $query=DB::Table(....) //query without order by
else
    $query=DB::Table(....)  //query with order by
```

I tried with 2 selects where 2nd select was optional but 2nd select overwrites first select.

Any good way to do this?

Comment: @TimLewis say what? Since when there is different case sensitivity in PHP depending on the environment? These are language-specific, they don't have anything to do with the environment.

Comment: @RoboRobok I've had many instances of mistyping a method/class name in my `local` environment (like `userrole` instead of `userRole`) and not having any issues, but pushing said change to `staging` or `production` and getting a `Class not found error`. I'm not sure if it was the PHP version being different or something else, but that's what I was referring to. I can see that my wording as "PHP environment" is maybe a bit misleading, when I mean to say "different development environments"...

Comment: @TimLewis function and method names have always been case-insensitive in PHP, period.

Comment: @RoboRobok Ok, so it must have been a class name then. I can remove my initial comment and recommend the correct case (by "correct" I mean as it's defined in Laravel's source).

Comment: Class names are case insensitive too. You probably either remembered it wrong or had the method/class missing and magic method doing something that caused error on staging.

Comment: @RoboRobok I'm not remembering it wrong, it was literally yesterday, with literally the example I gave. `$userRole = new Userrole();` worked locally, but crashed staging. `UserRole.php` is the file, with `class UserRole extends Model { ... }`

Comment: Then it must have been the file missing or something. I don't think there are case-sensitivity variations in any language, that would be super confusing and error-prone.

Comment: i'm under a case sensitive enviroment (aka php over linux), and yes, good practices are welcome but robo robok has reason too :)

Comment: You mean the file names, not functions/methods/classes. So the autoload won't find the file `MyCat.php` if it requests `Mycat.php`, that's it. But the classes themselves are still case-insensitive.

Comment: @TimLewis by the way, maybe that was the case with you :)

Comment: @RoboRobok Was that a pun? Case? Get it? Haha. And yeah, I'm seeing what you're saying, and that makes total sense.

Comment: If your local was Windows and the staging was some sort of UNIX then we probably solved that mystery. And yes, that was a pun, but just a little. CASE closed haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the columns in `get()` as an array instead of `select()`:

```php
$columns = ['Name', $select[0]];

if ($condition) {
    $columns[] = $orderBy;
}

DB::table('Enemies')->get($columns);
```

If for some reason you want to stick to `select()`, you still use it instead:

```php
DB::table('Enemies')->select($columns)->get();
```

Comment: it is in select not in order by the problem

Comment: I'm using cursors, not get, i dont know if that works

Comment: `cursor()` method doesn't get columns as an argument.

Comment: Would this work DB:table('Enemies')->Select($columns) based in your example?

Comment: Yes. Along with your `cursor()` in the end. Just use `select()` like you did before.

Comment: then change your ->get to ->select ( i have tested it already and it works ) and it is done :), thanks :). To accept the answer.

Comment: I'm keeping `get()`, because most people use `select()` without needing it. Let's keep it like that for the future.

Comment: the reason is that i'm using a 4millions row table, and then i pass a cursor, not get :)

Comment: I have never used cursor, I used `paginate()`, which takes columns as a parameter. Not sure why `cursor()` doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, but it also runs the query.